# Access name of instantiated object without additional property nor init method

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the below `BNREmployee.m` implementation file I am trying to override the default `description` and would like to be able to access the object name `john` assigned at instantiation in the main.m file. Is there a way to do this WITHOUT creating a separate "name" property or instance variable, and WITHOUT creating a separate init method where that name would be passed in?

**main.m file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRPerson.h"
#import "BNREmployee.h"
#import "BNREmployer.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        BNREmployee *john = [BNREmployee new];
        BNREmployer *costco = [BNREmployer new];
        [john setEmployer:costco];
        [costco setEmployeesList:[NSMutableSet setWithObject:john]];
        
        NSLog(@"employee: \n%@", john);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**BNREmployee.m file:**

```
#import "BNREmployee.h"

@implementation BNREmployee

-(NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Employee %@ with id: %d and employer: %@", [self ???***???], self.employeeId, self.employer];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for a class to know the name of a variable it's been assigned to. Keep in mind that you can assign one instance of `BNREmployee` (or any other class) to more than one variable.

```objc
BNREmployee *bob = [BNREmployee new];
BNREmployee *john = bob;
NSLog(@"employee = %@", bob);
NSLog(@"employee = %@", john);
```

In this case, how would the `description` method know the name? The one instance of the class has been assigned to two different variables.

Relying on the variable name makes little sense. If you want the `BNREmployee` class to keep track of a name then you must add a `name` property to the class. That's the whole point of a class - to keep track of state/data.

tl;dr - you can't do what you want. You must add a `name` property and optionally a custom `init` that lets you assign a name on creation.